# JOIN on list of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
ID|name1|fkey
1 |foo  |345, 567


ID |name2 |
345|hello |
567|world |
789|bar   |
```

So the first table has a list of keys in one cell.
How can I join these tables to get the following result:

```
ID |name2|name1
345|hello|foo
567|world|foo
789|bar  | <null>
```

A usual join does not work, because the column "fkey" contains lists of keys.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: This is not a good design.  In MSSQL you can split the field on the comma with a built in function now and do an select where IN your parsed values.  Not sure if that exists in postgresql built in but I am sure there is code out there you can find

Comment: This is not how foreign keys are supposed to be stored. Serializing FKs goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS.

Comment: please update the question with table schema information. Specifically, is `fkey` a comma-separated string, a postgres array, a json array or a jsonb array?

Comment: It was not me who stored the data like this. Unfortunately, I have to deal with it.

Comment: @HaleemurAli as far as I know, "fkey" is a usual comma-seperated string (text). "name1" and "name2" are usual texts, too.

Answer (score 1):

use `split_part()` and left join

```
select t2.*,a.name1 from t2 left join
(select id,name1, split_part(fkey,',',1) as key1 
from t1
union 
select id,name1, split_part(fkey,',',2) as key1 
from t1
) a on a.key=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an awful data format.  But you can do this in Postgres:

```
select t2.*, t1.name1
from t2 left join
     (t1 cross join lateral
      regexp_split_to_table(t1.fkey, ', ') r(val)
     )
     on t2.id = r.val;
```

Then, fix your data structure so you have a proper junction table!

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql if your column is an array you can do

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM table1 AS a
  JOIN table2 AS b on a.id = ANY(b.column_array)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/arrays.html